# Partial word match does not work with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've just downloaded version 1.5.2, and created a simple index:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/relman/users/ -d '{ "name": "ooppoopp" }'
```

But when I search for `oo` I got empty result:

```
curl 127.0.0.1:9200/relman/users/_search?q=oo
{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},
 "hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
```

Any ideas? It should work with default configuration

P.S From the mapping it looks like analyzer is active,

```
{
   "relman" : {
      "mappings" : {
         "users" : {
            "properties" : {
               "name" : {
                  "type" : "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per  **[partial matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html)** documentation you changed your query as

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/relman/users/_search?q=oo* //first
```

this check query which **starts with oo**

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/relman/users/_search?q=*oo* // second
```

this check query which **contain oo**

for example if inserted this

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/relman/users/ -d '{ "name": "ppoopp" }'
```

first query return only `ooppoopp` and second query return both `ooppoopp, ppoopp` respectively.

Another way to using **[wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)** as

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/relman/users/_search -d '
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "name": {
                "value": "oo*" // "*oo*"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```